# RestKit with local XML

Tags: objective-c, xml, restkit

I used RestKit to load XML data from a resource. That worked perfect, but now I want to change my whole program to read local XML files. I found the possibility to read a local xml file and parse it through RestKit in the Google RestKit Group:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testing" ofType:@"xml"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeXML]; 
id result = [parser objectFromString:string error:nil]; 
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[result objectForKey:@"sample"] objectForKey:@"nested"] objectForKey:@"tags" ] description]);
```

But now I want to load this object with my mapping. My old code with loading from a server:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKURL *URL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[objectManager baseURL] resourcePath:[xmlFile path] queryParameters:nil];

[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:myMapping forKeyPath:myKeyPath];

[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [URL resourcePath]] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.delegate = self;
}];
```

After that I get my mapped objects in the didLoadObjects delegate of RestKit. How can I do the same for my local xml object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution for the problem. Works like a charm.

```
RKObjectMappingProvider* mappingProvider = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider;
RKObjectMapper* mapper = [RKObjectMapper mapperWithObject:parsedData mappingProvider:mappingProvider];
RKObjectMappingResult* result = [mapper performMapping];
if (result) {

    NSArray *resultArray = result.asCollection;

    MyMappingClass *object = [resultArray lastObject];
    NSLog(@"My Object: %@", object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Restkit 0.20, I use this method:

library.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <bookname>azeaze</bookname>
    <bookname>qdd</bookname>
    <bookname>vvef</bookname>
    <bookname>ytrtefc</bookname>
</library>
```

Book.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Book : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * label;

@end
```

Book.m

```
#import "Book.h"

@implementation Book

@end
```

I create a NSDictionary with this XML file, for this I use [XMLReader](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/)

```
#import "XMLReader.h"

[...]

RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Book class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"bookname": @"label",}];

NSString *pathToDataFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"library"
                                                           ofType:@"xml"];

NSError *error;

NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToDataFile
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                  error:&error];

NSData* xmlData = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *parseError = nil;

NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:xmlData
                                                        error:&parseError];

NSDictionary *mappingsDictionary = @{ @"library": mapping };

RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:xmlDictionary
                                                           mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];

NSError *mappingError = nil;

BOOL isMapped = [mapper execute:&mappingError];

if (isMapped && !mappingError) {
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS : %@",[mapper mappingResult]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"FAIL : %@",mappingError);
}
```